# File won't delete

Tags: java, file

for some reason my file won't delete using f.delete(); and temp.txt will not be renamed to Materials.txt. I couldn't figure out what was wrong, it outputted false, I ran NetBeans as administrator in order to make sure it had permissions to delete the file, and the code before which is taking the editing a line works fine, other than the fact it is on temp which is not being changed to Materials.txt. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
try {
    DefaultTableModel model= (DefaultTableModel)Table.getModel();
    int selectedRowIndex = Table.getSelectedRow();

    File f= new File("Materials.txt");
    File file1= new File("temp.txt");
    FileReader fr= new FileReader("Materials.txt");
    BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(fr);
    FileWriter fw= new FileWriter("temp.txt", true);

    String updated = (jTextField1.getText()+","+jTextField2.getText()+","+jTextField3.getText()+","+jTextField4.getText()+","+jTextField5.getText()+","+jTextField6.getText()+"\r\n");
    String temp;
    int a=0;

    while (a<=selectedRowIndex)
    {
        a++;
        String line= br.readLine();
        fw.write(line+"\r\n");
    }
    br.readLine();
    fw.write(updated);

    while (br.ready()==true)
    {
        temp=br.readLine();
        fw.write(temp+"\r\n");
    }

    fw.close();
    br.close();
    fr.close();

    System.out.println(f.delete());
    file1.renameTo(f);
}
catch (IOException e){
    System.err.println(e);
}
```

Edit: Updated code trying to implement a suggest solution, the line with "void updateMaterialsFile(int updatedLineno = 0, String updated) throws IOException {" is throwing errors stating illegal start of expression, expecting ; (multiple times) and not a statement. Ty as always.

```
try {
   DefaultTableModel model= (DefaultTableModel)Table.getModel();
   int selectedRowIndex = Table.getSelectedRow();


   String updated = (jTextField1.getText()+","+jTextField2.getText()+","+jTextField3.getText()+","+jTextField4.getText()+","+jTextField5.getText()+","+jTextField6.getText()+"\r\n");

  void updateMaterialsFile(int updatedLineno = 0, String updated) throws IOException {
   Path materialsPath = Paths.get("Materials.txt");
   Path tempPath = materialsPath.resolveSibling("temp.txt");

   try (BufferedReader fr = Files.newBufferedReader(materialsPath);
           BufferedWriter fw = Files.newBufferedWriter(tempPath);) {

       for (int lineno = 0; ; ++lineno) {
           String line = fr.readLine();
           if (line == null) {
               break;
           }
           fw.write(lineno == updatedLineno ? updated : line);
           fw.write("\r\n");
       }
   } // Automatically closes fr and fw
   Files.move(tempPath, materialsPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
}
catch (IOException e){
   System.err.println(e);
}
```

Comment: 1) **Don't** add irrelevant tags like [tag:jframe]. 2) **Do** add relevant tags like [tag:file].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely clear about a timing problem for the deletion, as everything seems to be closed at least once.

```
void updateMaterialsFile(int updatedLineno, String updated) throws IOException {
    Path materialsPath = Paths.get("Materials.txt");
    Path tempPath = materialsPath.resolveSibling("temp.txt");

    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(materialsPath);
            BufferedWriter fw = Files.newBufferedWriter(tempPath)) {

        AtomicInteger lineno = new AtomicInteger();
        lines.forEach(line -> {
            int lno = lineno.getAndIncrement();
            try {
                fw.write(lno == updatedLineno ? updated : line);
                fw.write("\r\n");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        throw new IOException(e.getCause());
    }
    Files.move(tempPath, materialsPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

- The code above uses a newer style, the temp file uses the same file system in Path.
- The rename (move) does the deleting in one step.
- You could also use a temporary file (see Files), which might be on a faster file system.
- Using try-with resources automatically closes, even when returning, breaking, throwing an exception.
- A Stream version is used for reading, which has one drawback: the passed lambda may not throw an IOException. Also the "loop counter" `lineno` must not be assigned to, so cannot be an int. Maybe use `Files.newBufferedReader`.

---

***Simpler:***

The class [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) one should know, as it provides many utility calls.

```
/** @param updateLineno counted from 0. */
void updateMaterialsFile(int updatedLineno, String updated) throws IOException {
    Path materialsPath = Paths.get("Materials.txt");
    Path tempPath = materialsPath.resolveSibling("temp.txt");

    try (BufferedReader fr = Files.newBufferedReader(materialsPath);
            BufferedWriter fw = Files.newBufferedWriter(tempPath)) {

        for (int lineno = 0; ; ++lineno) {
            String line = fr.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }
            fw.write(lineno == updatedLineno ? updated : line);
            fw.write("\r\n");
        }
    } // Automatically closes fr and fw
    Files.move(tempPath, materialsPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

-

Comment: Im going to be honest, I don't understand the new code you wrote although of course I appreciate the time you took to write it. I will look into the bullet points and see if that can help solve my problem, thanks!

Comment: Being honest is the highest quality for being professional. And try-with-resources is an ugly syntax, as are Streams. I have added a more readable alternative.

Comment: Hi, ty, the link is especially helpful. I still have some questions on how this works though, since this is for a project and I don't want to simply copy paste code, and how to put it in my code (Look at question). First, in my code I made it to copy everything before the updated line, and then put the updated line in, and copy the rest, however in your code you write "fw.write(lineno == updatedLineno ? updated : line);" Could you explain what is happening in this line, how does it distinguish the lines before the selected row, and after it, and replace update 1, cause its txt.

Comment: The if-then-else expression `-?-:-` will almost always print the read `line` except when the lineno is the updatedLineno, it will write the `updated` string. So it handles before and after the same, and merely replaces the lineno'th line. By the way you can test this method in a small separate program.

Comment: Ah so its the same thing, I still however don't know how to fix the errors my code was throwing while implementing it, could you please take a look above, thanks for all the help I appreciate it

Comment: Good news and bad news, I managed to implement it into my code by changing some stuff and some of the values, and it works... kinda. It still doesn't delete the Material.txt file and rename the temp.txt file, although for some reason it did work once. It is now however outputting and error so we have more information, "java.nio.file.FileSystemException: Materials.txt: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." Im guessing your probably asleep or something so wheneverr you or anyone else can help me I would appreciate it

Comment: (Living in Europe) Indeed sometimes an other application has the file open. It also can be the case your own application forgot a `close` while reading the file. For that try-with-resources is a solid countermeasure. Maybe somewhere else Materials.txt is read and not closed. Another countermeasure is using `Files.readAllLines` to read the entire file.

Comment: Late response, my bad, I found a unclosed buffered reader in my login page... if that was the cause of my issues all along I can say atleast I learned some new code :0

Answer (score 0):

What I assume is going on: you do not have file temp.txt; You create FileWriter, which will create temp.txt and output to it. However, your variable file1 was initialized before filewriter created it. (Btw, you can check if file exists with File#exists). So you can do many things to change it, but the easiest would be to move initialization of new File("temp.txt") to the end of the method. This way you are sure it was created and will be able to rename it successfully

Comment: I tried to move the temp.txt to after the Filewriter as you suggested and it didn't fix anything, although you were correct in saying that temp.txt does not and is created at the start of he code.